# Webrtc server for mobile application

Tags: ios, webrtc

I want to create mobile apps using webRTC APIs. My basic need is one-to-one video calling capability. Should I just use an open source webRTC server like openwebrtc? I want it to handle at least 5k clients. Is there any other option to fulfill my needs?

Comment: https://www.linphone.org

Answer (score 2):

This question is very broad (and this isn't a proper answer), and is likely to attract very opinionated answers, and is also likely to be deemed as off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Having said that, if you can provide more information, you might get some reasonable opinions.

Please provide more information about what is important to you.

As WebRTC is a peer-to-peer system, scaling isn't a major issue. You need a signalling server of some kind to do call establishment. That work is over quite quickly, and then the two parties can continue the call without needing the server any more.

I don't have experience with openwebrtc, but I have used PeerJS, and found it to be quite good. It hasn't been updated in 2 years, but it seems to do the job pretty well, and is quite lightweight.

There are some commercial offerings around, but I question the value, as they leverage heavily from the open source components, and rely on the browsers for support. They are probably worth using if you want to do many-to-many video calling, as that is when you need a video server.

WebRTC is supposed to be easy, and it has been in the browsers for several years now (notably excluding Safari and IOS). It is a difficult area, and will take some time to master.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable information. I'd like to know if openwebrtc or peerJS are capable of handling around 5k clients, If I host them on my own server? Thats my basic requirement.

Comment: As I said, the need for a signalling server is momentary during call establishment. If you have 5k users all making a call at exactly the same moment, you will need to take it seriously. How many calls per hour or minute do you anticipate?

Comment: I am expecting 5k users per hour.

Comment: ok, so if you are going to handle 5k calls per hour, that's 83 calls per minute, which isn't too bad. You should look for a solution that is going to get you say 200 calls per minute (to deal with peak load). A single peerjs server might well be capable of that, but it's something you can benchmark to make sure (in fact you should run that test on any solution you are considering)

Comment: Thank you. I'll be testing with openwebrtc for now.

Comment: Does peerJS supports ios and android implementations?

Comment: Peerjs is a signalling server, it's pure javascript. There is a client library which runs in all browsers without problem

Answer (score 0):

OpenWebRTC project is a reasonable option for a basic video calling native mobile app; its [signalling server](https://github.com/EricssonResearch/openwebrtc-examples/tree/master/web) is only a basic demo, all written in JavaScript. As such, it should not crash on 5K simultaneous peer video connections.

But a real-world solution might require much more than this: TURN and STUN services, backup for the moments of hardware failure, load balancing, statistics and administration interfaces. Take security seriously: you should be able to cut out a spammer or other offender, in addition to protection against hackers.

Server software is that can help you will not necessarily cost much. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/38810518/192373.

Comment: I read that openwebrtc mobile sdk is not ready for the production yet. are there any other open servers which provide mobile app support?

Comment: You have Asterisk which is GPL and definitely ready for production.